# Removing/ignoring all the punctuation in a given string

Tags: java

I am trying to remove every punctuation from my string: So far, I've done the following :

```
String line = "there's, isn't";

line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "")
```

yet, this can't change "there's" into "theres" or "isn't" into "isnt".

I thought \p{Punct} includes every punctuation, including " ' " (as it's shown in api) yet this doesn't work. Can someone pls help?

Thanks in advance.

PS: expected outcome is: `theres isnt`

Comment: Given the input `there's, isn't`, what is your expected output?  If you want to transform contractions like `isn't` into `is not`, you will have to do a bunch more work.

Comment: my expected output is "theres isnt"

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in Java. String methods don't change the string in place, but instead return a modified copy of the string, so you need to assign the result back to the variable:

```
String line = "there's, isn't";

line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");

System.out.println(line); // theres isnt
```

Comment: Answer is correct but it has got nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Sure it has. String methods don't change the string in place due to their immutable nature, but instead return a modified copy of the string.

Comment: It's just an assignment problem. There is no assignment. Although this is correct *String methods don't change the string in place*. But not *due to their immutable nature*.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat So, according to you, what other design considerations might have gone into designing the language in a way that string operations don't operate on the string itself? Or: why do most operations on other types of objects change the object itself, but operations on thinks like `String`, `Integer`, etc. return a copy?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat From the [oracle tutorial on strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html): *"The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is create and return a new string that contains the result of the operation."*

Comment: *So, according to you, what other design considerations might have gone into designing the language in a way that string operations don't operate on the string itself*, the biggest reason that I can think of is to refer back to the original string and compare it with the replaced one. Just like Git version comparison.

Comment: Also I don't know what you think the relevance of the link you have commented. Can you explain?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Why does that same reasoning not apply to other objects then? About the link: it's an *authoritative* source that explains that the fact that string operations return a new string is due to their immutability. A fact that you keep on disputing.

Comment: Because there is a difference between pass by reference vs pass by value. You know what, let's just end this because it looks like both are stubborn. You won and I loose.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said, the strings are immutable and once created you can't really change it. So once you code like `String line = "there's, isn't";`the string object `"there's, isn't"`  will be created and `line` variable will be assigned to it. Java doesn't have the concept of pointers, but you can think of it as `line` variable pointing to the given string `"there's, isn't"`. Now your next line `line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "")` returns a newly created string object. You can assign it to another variable, say `line_cleared=line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""` and print that out: So here is the fully updated code:

```
String line = "there's, isn't";
line_cleared= line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
System.out.println(line_cleared);
```